# Highlight top 3 in ggplot2 with vector of colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a code below and I would like to color the top 3 with the selected colors. Many thanks in advance.

```
    library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(dose = c("D0.5", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5"),
                 len = c(4.2, 10, 29.5, 5, 7, 15))

df <- dplyr::mutate(df, top3 = rank(-len) %in% 1:3)


# Basic barplot
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(dose, -len), y = len)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = ifelse(df$top3 == TRUE,  c("blue", "yellow", "green"), "grey50")) + 
           #color = ifelse(df$top3 == TRUE,  c("red", "yellow", "green"), "grey50")) +
  coord_flip()
p
```

Comment: I can't see your comment anymore but yes you can change the legend by using the `labels` argument when creating the `rank` column - I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(dose = c("D0.5", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5"),
                 len = c(4.2, 10, 29.5, 5, 7, 15))

df <- df |> 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(len)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    rank = factor(dplyr::row_number(), labels = dose)
  )

fill_colors = c("blue", "yellow", "green")
other_colors = rep("grey50", nrow(df)-length(fill_colors))
my_scale  <- c(fill_colors, other_colors)

withr::with_options(
  list(ggplot2.discrete.fill = my_scale),
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(dose, -len), y = len)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = rank)) +
  scale_fill_discrete() +
  coord_flip()
)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate. thank you very much.

Comment: Apologies just realised there was a mismatch between the labels and the rank - I have updated the code to fix.

Comment: This call to withr seems absolute overkill here. Why not just using scale_fill_manual? also, you can leave coord_flip if you swap the aesthetic. `ggplot(data = df, aes(y = reorder(dose, -len), x = len)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = rank)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values= my_scale) ` really does the same trick and is much more readable. Also, I recommend using the reprex package. Referencing packages with :: is laudable, but you're easily running into failing code. Here missing: `dplyr::row_number()`,

Comment: You are right that `row_number` needs a `dplyr::` to be consistent. I have amended. As to whether `scale_fill_manual` is better than supplying your own palette to `scale_fill_discrete`, I like being explicit whether the scale is discrete or continuous, but I don't really think it matters as they do the same thing.  If you do use `scale_fill_discrete` then the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_colour_discrete.html) suggests using `withr`. If you don't think you should use it here, are there any circumstances where you would prefer it over `scale_fill_manual`?

Comment: Yes, I'd clearly use it when I don't need to provide manual color mapping (in most cases). However, I use `scale_fill_brewer` or even `colorblindr::scale_fill_okabeIto` in most cases. Regarding the withr:: call: In this case, your 6-7 lines of code can be shortened to 3 lines. I think especially in the case of stackoverflow it would be good to keep the code as concise as possible in order to keep the focus to the actual problem and not to create a new question mark

Answer (score 2):

A slight twist to the other suggested options, with less code. I think your idea of an if else statement is generally ok - however, your use with $ in aes seems dangerous. The reason we can do this is that the number of top rows matches the length of your color vector (in this case: 3)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(dose = c("D0.5", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5"),
                 len = c(4.2, 10, 29.5, 5, 7, 15))

mycols <- c("blue", "yellow", "green")

df <- df %>%
  arrange(desc(len)) %>%
  mutate(fills = ifelse(row_number() <= length(mycols), mycols, "grey50"))

## swapping x and y makes coord_flip obsolete
## using I in aes is the same as adding "scale_fill_identity" at the end
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = len, y = reorder(dose, -len))) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = I(fills)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

you can add an additional color rank column in you data frame and change the colors accordinly with `scale_fill_manual`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(dose = c("D0.5", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5"),
                 len = c(4.2, 10, 29.5, 5, 7, 15))

df <- dplyr::mutate(df, top3 = rank(-len))
df <- dplyr::mutate(df, col_rank = as.character( ifelse(top3 > 3, 4, top3)))

# Basic barplot
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(dose, -len), y = len, fill = col_rank)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "yellow", "3" = "green", "4" = "grey50"))
p
```